# use regex in a wrapped text value cell

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a cell like this :

```
1 parent
 1 child
```

I am getting the value  in vba :

```
Dim nbChild As String
Dim nbParent As String
Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(C.Row - 1, C.Column).Value
```

However, I would like to put the number of parent and child in 2 separates variables nbParent and nbChild, so I was thinking to use regex to capture the groups (digit number before parent and digit number before child).

But I don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you supply some data, an example and an output of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Is there a hard return in that cell you show, is is the text just wrapped? If there is a return you can use `Split(yourValueHere,chr(10))` and then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim arr, parent, child

arr = Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))'split on hard return
parent=arr(0)
child=arr(1)

'then split each line on space....
debug.print Split(parent," ")(0) 'number
debug.print Split(parent," ")(1) 'text

debug.print Split(child," ")(0) 'number
debug.print Split(child," ")(1) 'text
```

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

click on a cell and run:

```
Sub Family()
    ary = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
    nParent = CLng(ary(0))
    nChild = CLng(ary(2))
    MsgBox nParent & vbCrLf & nChild
End Sub
```

*(regex is not necessary)*

Comment: The problem is that my cell is not like this, On the first line there is 1 parent, and on the second line there is 1 child, and it's stay like this whatever the width of the column. The option "automatically send to line (translation in french)" is activated.

Comment: @user2443476  **Please clarify the contents of a single cell.**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Gary's Student that you don't seem to need Regex but if you insist on it, I think the code below works.  You'll need to add in reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 from Tools -> References.

```
 Sub main()
        Dim value As String
        Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
        Dim matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
        Dim match As VBScript_RegExp_55.match

        value = Range("A1").value

        Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
        re.Pattern = "\d+"
        re.Global = True

        Set matches = re.Execute(value)

        For Each match In matches
            Debug.Print match.value
        Next

    End Sub
```